# barman + postgresql not start after barman retore

Tags: postgresql, restore, linux, barman

I use the barman for backup and restore

after some restore , we start the postgresql as the following

```
systemctl start postgresql.service
```

but postgresql not startup

from the log:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/backups/data/pg_log
```

we seen the following errors

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-08-06 07:30:49 UTC
LOG:  restored log file "00000008.history" from archive
LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2017-08-06 07:30:49.813508+00
LOG:  restored log file "0000000800000000000000C1" from archive
LOG:  redo starts at 0/C1000080
LOG:  recovery stopping before commit of transaction 96139, time 2017-08-06 07:30:49.855629+00
LOG:  redo done at 0/C1001B90
FATAL:  requested recovery stop point is before consistent recovery point
LOG:  startup process (PID 55858) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

please advice what is wrong configuration on BARMAN that cause this ?

Comment: It seems your missing some blocks in your WAL file 0000000800000000000000C1. Had you made a copy of your pg_xlog directory BEFORE restoring ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to restore to a point in time that is earlier than what is recorded in the backups.

Make sure you have not specified a recovery-time that is earlier than the backup you are trying to restore.

Check the files `recovery.conf` and `backup.label` in the postgres data directory.
If you want to restore to the latest possible, then you should make sure you don't have a property named `recovery_target_time` in the recovery.conf.